# Symfony, performance fails.While running heavy script on one path, other paths become inaccessible

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Today we found a problem in our Symfony Application. We did a simple stress test and it failed.
In our Controller, we have a function that renders records returned from database.
So just to test I tried to clog up the system with a loop,

```
 this function runs at path {baseurl}/countries
//$countries fetches all records from the "countries" table
for($i = 0; $i<=200000; $i++) {
         foreach ($countries as $country) {
             echo $country . '<br>';
         }
    }
```

Looped this array 2 million times, and while this was running, we tried accessing other paths within the same symfony which is nothing but a static twig template rendered from the controller. But even to render it, it took ages to do so.

Accessed `{baseurl}/register` which only contains static html form.

Checked for any syntax errors. None was there
Changed my OPCache settings according to [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html#performance-install-apcu-polyfill). Restarted server, rebooted the PC. No improvement whatsoever.

What should I do, its not my apache problem, I tried accessing other sites with my Apache and it loads up fine. `Htop` only shows apache using 13% of CPU, but my symfony application whilst executing one script, other paths become painfully inaccessible.
Im not sure what to do since its not my PC resources problem, its the framework performance issue. Is this problem normal ??

Comment: Are these tests run from the browser? And are you using the same browser to open the other pages? If so, the problem is probably that php has locked the session and you cannot open any other page until it is available again.

Comment: What do you mean by “it’s not my apache problem”? I think apache *is* the culprit.

Comment: @jeroen I tried from the same browser as well different browser

Comment: @ehymel If that were the case, my apache resource usage would be full up, I wouldn't be able to access other sites with my apache sites directory. Other sites work normally as if nothing happened.

Comment: @jeroen Yes exactly that

Comment: I’ve encountered the same thing. I think apache is dedicating single process to each website on the server. If you tie up that site with a long process on any of its pages, then the entire site is down until the process is killed or the script completes. This is not unique to symfony. I wish this was not the case, it’s very inconvenient. Other sites continue to function normally because plenty of resources are still available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is caused by the way PHP's "Session Locking"
https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/

```
# code copied from link above
<?php
...
// This works in PHP 5.x and PHP 7
session_start();

$_SESSION['something'] = 'foo';
$_SESSION['yolo'] = 'swag';

session_write_close();

// Do the rest of your PHP execution below
```

basically if you wan't to have non-blocking requests, you should just close the session before proceeding with heavy processing.